# How do I translate assembly code to C?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I'm having trouble understanding how to translate this assembly code to C. It is very short, only a few lines and the answer should be a one liner.

```
char_out:
    subq   $8, %esp
    movsbl  %dil, %edi    # Parameter 1 in %dil / %edi
    call    putchar       # put char is a C function that writes (prints)
    addq    $8, %rsp      # a single char to stdout (the screen).
    ret
```

```
void char_out(char P1)
{
    //insert here
}
```

Comment: it will be just `putchar(P1);`

Comment: Questions asking for somebody to do your work are not for StackOverflow. Show us what you've tried so far and where you got stuck and we'll be glad to help you.

Comment: @olivercharlesworth that was a nice joke but why did you change the link?

Comment: I understand that the assembly code has a pointer in it. The first line subq sets the flag. But I am not sure what the next line does for movsbl. The next line will call the defined put char method and the addq will be %rsp = %rsp + 8

Comment: Do not post code as an image.

Answer (score 2):

```
char_out:
    # Allocate 8 bytes on the stack by subtracting 8 from the stack pointer.
    # 
    # This is done for conformance to the calling convention expected by the
    # 'putchar' function, which we're about to call.
    subq   $8, %esp

    # This is the weirdo AT&T mnemonic for the MOVSX instruction, which does a
    # move with sign extension. This means that it extends a small value
    # (here, a BYTE-sized value in DIL) into a larger value (here, a
    # DWORD-sized value in EDI), in a way that properly accounts for the
    # value's sign bit.
    # 
    # This is necessary because the 'putchar' function expects to be passed a
    # 32-bit 'int' parameter.
    movsbl  %dil, %edi

    # It's obvious what this does: it calls the 'putchar' function.
    call    putchar

    # Clean up the stack, undoing what we previously did to the stack pointer
    # at the top of the function (the 'subq' instruction).
    addq    $8, %rsp
```

As Lashane already commented, this assembly code is equivalent to the following C code:

```
void char_out(char P1)
{
    putchar(P1);
}
```

or, I suppose you could also say:

```
void char_out(char P1)
{
    int temp = (int)P1;     // movsbl
    putchar(temp);
}
```

but the C compiler will do that implicitly for you, so it is not necessary to show that widening cast explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful. My only confusion is the purpose of the subq and addq in the assembly. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Not sure what else I can say that I didn't already say. Look up how the stack works on the x86 architecture. When you want to allocate space on the stack, you subtract from the stack pointer; when you want to free that space, you add to the stack pointer. The stack pointer is always stored in the `ESP` register, so that's what the `sub` and `add` instructions are doing. I also already explained *why* it's doing this, even though you aren't using the stack: the `putchar` function obviously expects this as part of its calling convention. That's implementation-dependent, so I can't say much more.

Comment: @ninchicken : Because the [64-bit System V ABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/x86-64-psABI-r252.pdf) requires it. In section _3.2.2 The Stack Frame_ it says "_The end of the input argument area shall be aligned on a 16 (32 or 64, if
__m256 or __m512 is passed on stack) byte boundary. In other words, the value
(%rsp + 8) is always a multiple of 16 (32 or 64) when control is transferred to
the function entry point. The stack pointer, %rsp, always points to the end of the
latest allocated stack frame_"